# Javascript Use a previous drop down box to justify the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am looking for a solution for my website. I have a form where a customer selects their device (eg iPhone 6s, Samsung GS6), but I would then like the data from that drop down box to transfer over to the next drop down box so they can select an available repair. If you need an example, go to my website ([www.warerepair.uk/booking.html](http://www.warerepair.uk/booking.html))

Comment: Per my understanding, you want to change data of some dropdown based on selection of another dropdown. Right? If yes, you can write a event for it. Example: `$(dropdown_first).on("change", handler)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want cascading drop-down then in that case you have to on first drop-down change event get first's drop-down selected value and using that value load second drop down.

Please see the below code

$('#firstDropdownID').on('change', function () {

```
        var searchVal = ($(this).find('option:selected').val());
      //Using this searchval load your second dropdown
```

});